# Jenkins java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, ant, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins and Selenium WebDriver with Ant. So far so good.
When I run the job in Jenkins, there is error in console:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\*****\.hudson\jobs\RunTest\workspace\build.xml

Sel:
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
```

Why this error shows? I have all necessary libs in the project. I have also `selenium-java-2.47.1` and `selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1`.
The build file:

```
    ...... more code .... 
        <path id="Sel.classpath">
            <pathelement location="bin"/>
            <path refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
            <pathelement location="../../libs/ojdbc7.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="../../libs/rs2xml.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="../../libs/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="../../libs/selenium-java-2.47.1.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="../../libs/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar"/>
        </path>
...... more code .... 

    <target name="Sel">
        <java classname="adminSection.TestCi" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="Sel.classpath"/>
        </java>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I create brand new project, remove `selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar` then Generate (from Extract) build.xml file. All libs are included in build file now.